# Where to find a reliable laptop battery replacement for ASUS K42N Series?

Tags: battery

I bought a battery from an e-commerce site with about 30 reviews from previous buyers, but I am worried if it might explode because it may not be the original battery provided by ASUS.

I just bought it a while ago, but then I suddenly saw a FB post of someone at school who placed their laptops in their bed, charging, then it blew up (luckily he wasn't even using it or near it when it did). If my laptop blew up while I was using it, my hand/finger would fly off and my face might get scarred given the magnitude of the explosion.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, part of the problem is putting things that get hot in your bed. You wouldn't put a burning log in bed would you? So don't charge laptops next your pillow either.

Comment: Definitely not going to do that. I'm just worried it'll burst in flames even on a table lol. The replacement battery is hard to find these days, i'm wondering where to purchase legitimate ones

Comment: Fair enough. I'll admit, it is hard to find reliable batteries and reputable dealers.